# how to limit _delete_by_query to a single type when using java client Api

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to delete some documents from es using java client, e.g

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_delete_by_query?conflicts=proceed" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
'
```

but from [document Apis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-delete-by-query.html)

```
BulkByScrollResponse response = DeleteByQueryAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(client)
    .filter(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("gender", "male")) 
    .source("persons")                                  
    .get();                                             
long deleted = response.getDeleted();
```

it seems you cannot `limit _delete_by_query to a single type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always do it like this:

```
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("_type", "tweet"))
    .filter(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("gender", "male"));

BulkByScrollResponse response = DeleteByQueryAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(client)
    .filter(query) 
    .source("persons")                                  
    .get();                                             
long deleted = response.getDeleted();
```